# Hiding some HTML from IE6?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6

I've tried:

```
<!--[if lt IE 6.0]>
HTML TO HIDE FROM IE6
<![endif]-->
```

but unfortunately the stuff gets hidden from firefox too. Anyone have methods that work? I want the stuff to be hidden from only IE6

Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can actually use conditional comments to hide things from Internet Explorer contrary to the answer from deceze. These types of conditional comments are called '[Downlevel Reveal Conditional Comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(VS.85).aspx#dlrevealed)'. (These are different from comments used to show things to internet explorer which are more common, those are known as 'Downlevel hidden conditional comments')

```
<!--[if lte IE 6]><![if gte IE 7]><![endif]-->
<!-- This is a bit mad, but code inside here is served to everything 
    except browsers less than IE7, so all browsers will see this -->
<!--[if lte IE 6]><![endif]><![endif]-->
```

However if you already using a downlevel hidden conditional comment to show a IE6 stylesheet just to IE6 then you might be best off just hiding it with CSS.

I hope this helps.

Comment: This is good, because it puts the <![]> constructs inside HTML comments, so the page will still validate.

Comment: +1, but there's a shorter and clearer version. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Little confused with your question but Here is the javascript code to detect the version of Internet Explorer. Taken from [Detecting Internet Explorer More Effectively](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537509%28VS.85%29.aspx). Add the HTML contents which are to be hidden from IE6 in a div and hide it using the function below.

```
function getInternetExplorerVersion()
// Returns the version of Internet Explorer or a -1
// (indicating the use of another browser).
{
  var rv = -1; // Return value assumes failure.
  if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer')
  {
    var ua = navigator.userAgent;
    var re  = new RegExp("MSIE ([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})");
    if (re.exec(ua) != null)
      rv = parseFloat( RegExp.$1 );
  }
  return rv;
}
function checkVersion()
{
  var msg = "You're not using Internet Explorer.";
  var ver = getInternetExplorerVersion();

  if ( ver > -1 )
  {
    if ( ver == 6.0 ) 

            **Hide the DIV here**

  }
  alert( msg );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<!--[if lte IE 6.0]>
```

in your CSS, using `lte` (less-than or equal) rather than `lt` (less-than).

Answer (score 0):

Conditional comments shouldn't affect Firefox at all as they are commented out and the browser should ignore it. I would check that your Firefox stylesheet is correct and embeded correctly something like this:

```
<link href="/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<link href="/css/ie6.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Edit

After reading [Natalie Downe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204505/hiding-some-html-from-ie6/1206179#1206179), I'd do it like this:

```
<!--[if true]><![if !IE]><![endif]-->
<h1>You're not using IE. Well done!</h1>
<!--[if true]><![endif]><![endif]-->
```

You can use **negated conditional comments** to hide things from IE but not from other browsers.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style type="text/css"></style>
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>

<![if !IE]>
<h1>You're not using IE. Well done!</h1>
<![endif]>

</body>
</html>
```

It renders some invalid markup, but it works.

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Natalie Downe's answer is good enough, but there's a shorter and clearer version to hide content from IE6 (or whatever version below 10):

```
<!--[if !IE 6]><!-->IE6 can't see me<!--<![endif]-->
```

To target IE6 *and below*, you can use

```
<!--[if gt IE 6]><!-->IE6 and lower can't see me<!--<![endif]-->
```

And if you want to support IE10+ only, you can use

```
<!--[if !IE]><!-->IE9 and lower can't see me<!--<![endif]-->
```

In fact, IE10+ doesn't support conditional comments. Inspired by [Browserhacks](http://browserhacks.com/).

Every other browser can see the content, of course, since it's all valid HTML.