# The opposite to an HTML conditional if statement?

Tags: html

In html you can include a file (such as a script or styletsheet) using  for example. Is there a way to do 'if not', so I could include the file for all browsers except one?

Comment: Except what browser? IE? See http://msdn.microsoft.com/ms537512.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`<!--[if !(IE 7)]><p>You are not using version 7.</p><![endif]-->`

Comment: Not a problem. Basically the ! sign means 'not' in various programming contexts.

Comment: Problem being that this says "if you're an *Internet Explorer* other than version 7", as all other browsers will just see an HTML comment and ignore it. Is that actually what was asked for by "all other browsers"?

Comment: See this answer for a way to hide things from specific IE versions, but show them in all other browsers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204505/hiding-some-html-from-ie6/1206179#1206179