# Is different html page content to different browsers possible?

Tags: html, css, browser, conditional-statements

I have a fullscreen/background slideshow that my client loves that just utterly fails in Internet Explorer 8 and below. I think trying to fix that is way beyond my capabilities right now so I would just like to switch it out for another IE safe background slideshow (less good looking but its something at least) if the browser is IE8 or below.

However, I know that you can switch stylesheets by using

```
<!--[if IE]>
```

etc, but the stylesheet relies on some basic html markup within a div (example below) that I do not want to show on the page to internet explorer ...

```
        <ul class="cb-slideshow">
        <li><span>Image 01</span><div><h3>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h3></div></li>
        <li><span>Image 02</span><div><h3>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h3></div></li>
        <li><span>Image 03</span><div><h3>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h3></div></li>
        </ul>
```

- how do I remove this if the user is using IE8 or below?  I am using a mac so running many tests in IE is not really possible so I am not being lazy in asking.

Do I just have to have different pages or something?

Thanks in advance

Comment: In your IE8 and less specific CSS file `<!--[if lt IE 9]> ... -->` you could choose not to display the content: `.cb-slideshow { display: none; }` Although the HTML would still be present, the user would not be able to see it. Or for some other reason do you have to remove the HTML?

Comment: Here's an example with IE6: [Hide when IE6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6782800/hide-a-specific-div-if-browser-is-ie6)

Comment: CC can be used *anywhere* in the document, not just the `<head>`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use conditional comments to set a class on the `<html>` tag you can avoid having a separate stylesheet:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>  <body class="ie ie6 lte9 lte8 lte7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>     <body class="ie ie7 lte9 lte8 lte7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>     <body class="ie ie8 lte9 lte8">      <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]>     <body class="ie ie9 lte9">           <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 9]>  <body class="ie">                    <![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!--> <body>                               <!--<![endif]-->
```

in your styles just hide the ul : `.lte9 .cb-slideshow { display: none;}`

see:

http://paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/

and

http://misteroneill.com/journal/improved-internet-explorer-targeting-through-body-classes/

Comment: As far as I understand, he doesn't just want to change the style, but the complete markup for each browser.

Comment: This answer technically *is* changing the markup.  Conditional Comments aren't limited to the `<head>` of the document, they can be used in the `<body>` as well.

Comment: Perhaps a better solution would be to start with the IE8 single image solution as a default, then add the other images either with conditionals in the body or javascript. Progressive enhancement and all that.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on one of the comments, you can put conditional comments anywhere, so you can do this:

```
<!--[if lt IE9]>// IE-specific slideshow HTML here. <![endif]-->
<!--[if gte IE 9]><!-->// Standard slideshow HTML here (for IE9+ and non-IE browsers) <!--<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 <!--[if !LT IE 9]><!-->
 <p>Not IE 8 and below and all other browsers</p>
 <!--<![endif]-->

 <!--[if lt IE 9]>
 <p>IE 8 and below </p>
 <![endif]-->
```

The first block outputs to all browsers except IE8 and below. 
The second block outputs to IE8 and below.

Answer (score -1):

You can define different layout inside `<div id="browserid" style="display:none">...</div>`-Tags where browserid is one of IE, FF, etc. That makes them invisible by default.

Then you define a javscript function, that is called at onpageLoad and that evaluates the `navigator.userAgent` property. That contains the client browser name. Depending on that value you change the corresponding 's display-style.

Comment: Brilliant - kicking myself now :-) Thanks very much

Comment: Making things invisible by default is not a best-practice

Comment: @ScottSimpson: Granted. But, in this case, what would be the best practice? I assume, you could make an ajax request at the pageload, passing the userAgent and getting the markup returned by some server app. But since that was not explicitly asked for, I omitted it.

Comment: @ScottSimpson Thanks alot. Just learned something new. That's why I love this page.