# Disable all JavaScript and jQuery in one HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-6

I have a WordPress website and I have installed one plugin and the plugin has some problems in IE6 browser.

So, I want to disable that jQuery plugin when the page is viewed with the  IE6 browser.

**So now I need a jQuery statement to disable ALL other statements that are loading from other JS files.**

Comment: Please check [THIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28VS.85%29.aspx) out

Comment: `IE6` , come-on man ... `Microsoft Ends Support for Windows XP`

Comment: You'll have to be a lot more clear on what you really want to do.  Do you want to disable the entire page in IE6?  One might also ask why, in 2014, you are even worrying about IE6?  You could just hide the whole body content on IE6 and inject a one line message that says that IE6 is not supported.

Comment: @BatuZet I said i need JS statement. Not HTML ;)

Comment: @AmitSoni Yeah, But It has many many users for me :(

Comment: @jfriend00 You are right! but here , MANY users use this shi..t browser :|

Comment: please provide some code , including `html` part & `jQuery` part

Comment: @AmitSoni :| No need to codes ! Just i need One JS statement to DISABLE other !

Comment: if you want to disable all the events on each elements on the page try this `$("*").off();`

Comment: @AmitSoni NOT worked.

Comment: what actually that plugin do?

Comment: @AmitSoni the problem happens when the mouse focuses on input element. Its jQuery Validation Plugin 1.9.0

Comment: @AmitSoni Problem is that when mouse focuses on one input, then all the entire form will be disappear ! SO, i want to detect if it is IE, then form valid Not work. just this.

Comment: what you can do is first make a clone of that div which contains that form for e.g. if div id is myDiv so do this `var cloneDiv = $("#myDiv").clone();` then remove the original div present in document like so `$("#myDiv").remove();` and then just append the clone div , suppose that div was present inside another div with id parentDiv so do like this `$("#parentDiv").html(cloneDiv);` by this you can avoid the plugin attachment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use Downlevel-revealed conditional comments :

```
<!--[if lte IE 6]><![if gte IE 7]><![endif]-->

<!-- keep your script in between these two comments, 
it will work in all browser except ie -->

<!--[if lte IE 6]><![endif]><![endif]-->
```

Explained here : [Hiding some HTML from IE6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204505/hiding-some-html-from-ie6)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure why IE6 is even on your agenda, but to each their own.

If it were me I would write something like this.

```
<!doctype html>
    <!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html class="ie6"> <![endif]-->....
    .....


(function ($) {
    "use strict";

    // Detect IE 6
    var greatGreatGranddadsBrowser;
    if ($('html').is('.ie6')) {
        greatGreatGranddadsBrowser = true;
    }

    if (greatGreatGranddadsBrowser) {
        // Remove the elements that you don't want loaded
        // Tell the users to seriously consider coming into the real world
    } else {
        // Do whatever else you need to do 
    }

}(jQuery));
```